# AWStats a network drive

Tags: windows, networking, batch, awstats

I am running AWStats from a NAS networked drive on a Windows network.  The apache sever log files are also on the NAS network drive and the path includes the network drive letter along with locations for the log files and AWStats.

I am running AWStats from a batch file also located on the NAS network drive from a Windows task.

This setup works fine on 3 of the 8 Windows machines, but AWStats fails with a syntax error on the other five.    I know the network drive is fine because Apache Server starts on all the computers successfully.

I am running ActivePerl 5.28 and AWStats 7.9.   The computers are a mix of Windows 10 and 11. The batch file runs successfully on one Windows 11 computer and two Windows 10 computers.

All of the computers are mapped to the network drive the same way at startup.  The account names on all the computers are the same.   The computers mapped to the network drive with both the Local Account and the SYSTEM account.  There is no data for AWStats on the local drives.

What would cause a AWStats to fail on some computers, but not others running from the exact same batch file?

Thanks